# Cannot prepend div that was clicked with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to prepend a div with a certain class, but i can't get it to work. I want to get a copy of the current li selected from the top nav, and send it to the other nav as an h2 title. I tried targeting the class "current" and then getting it's value and prepeding it to the other nav, but it didn't work. Sorry if this sounds confusing, but you will understand once you check out the run the code snippet. Thanks for you help!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var collageID = $('.collegeTypeNav .tab').first().addClass('current').data('tabid');
    var aboutID = $('.aboutCollegeNav .tab').first().addClass('current').data('tabid');
    showDiv();

    $('.collegeTypeNav .tab').click(function(){
        $('.collegeTypeNav .tab').removeClass('current');
        collageID = $(this).addClass('current').data('tabid');
        showDiv();
    });

    $('.aboutCollegeNav .tab').click(function(){
        $('.aboutCollegeNav .tab').removeClass('current');
        aboutID = $(this).addClass('current').data('tabid');
        showDiv();
    });

    function showDiv(){
        $('.mainContent > div').hide();
        if(collageID && aboutID){
            $('.mainContent').find('[data-blockid="'+collageID +' ' + aboutID + '"]').show();
        }
    }

    //get text of the li that is currently clicked from the top nav to go inside the other nav as an h2.
    var toAdd = $('.collegeTypeNav .tab .current').text();
    var item = $("<h2>" + toAdd + "</h2");
    $('.aboutCollegeNav').prepend(item);
});
```

```css
.current{
    background: red;
} 
nav ul{
    list-style: none;
}
li{
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 20px;
}
li:hover{
    background: red;
}
.mainNav ul{
    display: flex
}
.mainNav ul li{
    margin-right: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.collegeTypeNav{
    background: #c4d8ff;
}
.collegeTypeNav ul{
    display: flex;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
.collegeTypeNav ul li{
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.middleContent{
    display: flex;
}
.aboutCollegeNav{
    background: #d1ffe4;
}
.aboutCollegeNav ul{
    padding: 0px;
}
.aboutCollegeNav ul li{
    margin-bottom: 10px;    
}

.mainContent{
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
      <nav class="collegeTypeNav">
         <ul>
            <li role="button" class="tab" data-tabid="engineering">Engineering</li>
            <li role="button" class="tab" data-tabid="science">Science</li>
            <li role="button" class="tab" data-tabid="liberalArts">Liberal Arts</li>
         </ul>
      </nav>
      <div class="middleContent">
         <nav class="aboutCollegeNav">
            <ul>
               <li role="button" class="tab" data-tabid="overview">Overview</li>
               <li role="button" class="tab" data-tabid="statistics">Statistics</li>
               <li role="button" class="tab" data-tabid="courses">Courses</li>
            </ul>
         </nav>
         <div class="mainContent">
            <div data-blockid="engineering overview">
               <p>This is the inside of engineering overview</p>
            </div>
            <div data-blockid="science courses">
               <p>This is the inside of science courses</p>
            </div>
            <div data-blockid="liberalArts overview">
               <p>This is the inside of science courses liberalarts overview</p>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The first 3 lines of your function run as soon as the DOM is loaded (document.ready) instead of when a top nav item is clicked. And the first line searches for `.current` before the 4th line adds that class to anything. Try moving those lines to the appropriate handler.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't fix it.

Comment: your code seems to work fine, check [link](https://jsfiddle.net/c89vdwmL/)

Comment: That's a lot of code for prepending a div... Is there any way you can trim that down to just the part you're having a problem with; a [mre]?

Comment: Sorry. I just deleted 50% of the HTML code. I hope it's not too long now.

Comment: Dean Van Greunen, I think you didn't understand the problem that i'm having. I want the text of the li that is currently clicked from the top nav to go inside the other nav as an h2.

Comment: `val()` method is for getting values of form elements. You need to use `text()` in your situation.

Comment: Thanks EternalHour! But unfortunately that didn't fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to accomplish your goal there are several things you need to do. This could definitely be more efficient but just improving what you have.

1. Add the `current` class to your default nav item ("Engineering"). Also, rather than creating the `<h2>` every time, I added it to the html so it's always there and just needs to have content.

   ```
   <nav class="collegeTypeNav">
     <ul>
       <li role="button" class="tab current" data-tabid="engineering">Engineering</li>
       <li role="button" class="tab" data-tabid="science">Science</li>
       <li role="button" class="tab" data-tabid="liberalArts">Liberal Arts</li>
     </ul>
   </nav>

   <nav class="aboutCollegeNav">
     <h2 class="navHeading"></h2>
     <ul>
       <li role="button" class="tab" data-tabid="overview">Overview</li>
       <li role="button" class="tab" data-tabid="statistics">Statistics</li>
       <li role="button" class="tab" data-tabid="courses">Courses</li>
     </ul>
   </nav>
   ```
2. I created a dedicated function for updating the `<h2>` to make it more versatile.

   ```
     $(document).ready(function() {
     var collageID = $('.collegeTypeNav .tab').first().addClass('current').data('tabid');
     var aboutID = $('.aboutCollegeNav .tab').first().addClass('current').data('tabid');
     var defaultTab = $('nav.collegeTypeNav').find('.current').text();
     updateH2(defaultTab);
     showDiv();

     $('.collegeTypeNav .tab').click(function() {
       $('.collegeTypeNav .tab').removeClass('current');
       collageID = $(this).addClass('current').data('tabid');
       updateH2($(this).text());
       showDiv();
     });

     $('.aboutCollegeNav .tab').click(function() {
       $('.aboutCollegeNav .tab').removeClass('current');
       aboutID = $(this).addClass('current').data('tabid');
       showDiv();
     });

     function updateH2(toAdd) {
       $('.navHeading').text(toAdd);
     }

     function showDiv() {
       $('.mainContent > div').hide();
       if (collageID && aboutID) {
         $('.mainContent').find('[data-blockid="' + collageID + ' ' + aboutID + '"]').show();
       }
     }
   });
   ```

Comment: Thanks! But how do you have engineering as the default h2 without hard-coding it?

Comment: @Charly - You would just add `showDiv("Engineering");`, see my updated answer.

Comment: thanks! But the issue is that i will use this algorithm for multiple pages/navs so it's not a good idea to hard code it in the HTML or in the JS like your comment above. Or is it not possible?

Comment: @Charly - In that case you need a default current tab then you select it when the page loads. Answer updated.

Comment: the issue now it that the h2 now changes to the current li of that nav(aboutCollegeNav).

Comment: @Charly - That's more than likely because I added `var toAdd = $(this).text();` to that click event, just remove it. This is why you need to provide an example of the expected behavior in your question. We can't guess exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: for some reason when I remove that line, the bottom nav won't work.

Comment: The reason for these issues is because the `showDiv()` function has to run in order to show the content. Inside the `showDiv()` function, it always expects to update the `<h2>` because it's hard coded there. Hopefully this makes sense. The `<h2>` needs to be created/updated conditionally only when the `.collegeTypeNav` click event happens.

Comment: @Charly - Please check my final answer.

Answer (score 0):

update js code.

Add Default H2 in aboutCollegeNav

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var collageID = $('.collegeTypeNav .tab').first().addClass('current').data('tabid');
    var aboutID = $('.aboutCollegeNav .tab').first().addClass('current').data('tabid');
    showDiv();

    $('.collegeTypeNav .tab').click(function(){
        $('.collegeTypeNav .tab').removeClass('current');
        $('.aboutCollegeNav >h2').html($(this).html());
        collageID = $(this).addClass('current').data('tabid');
        showDiv();
    });


    $('.aboutCollegeNav .tab').click(function(){
        $('.aboutCollegeNav .tab').removeClass('current');
        aboutID = $(this).addClass('current').data('tabid');
        showDiv();
    });

    function showDiv(){
        $('.mainContent > div').hide();
        if(collageID && aboutID){
            $('.mainContent').find('[data-blockid="'+collageID +' ' + aboutID + '"]').show();
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="aboutCollegeNav">
     <h2>engineering</h2>
    <ul>
       <li role="button" class="tab" data-tabid="overview">Overview</li>
       <li role="button" class="tab" data-tabid="statistics">Statistics</li>
       <li role="button" class="tab" data-tabid="courses">Courses</li>
    </ul>
 </nav>
```

Comment: Thanks! But is there a way to get the default h2 dynamically instead of hard coding it?